# Flutter - convert dropdownformfield to autocompleteFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dropdownFormField which takes data from snapshot and working fine.
now the data has grown bigger, as such want to change it to autocompleteFormField.

The code for dropdownFormField I am using is like this:

```
Container(
                                height: 50.0,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
                                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                    child: ButtonTheme(
                                  child: FutureBuilder(
                                      future: _testkit,
                                      builder: (context,
                                          AsyncSnapshot<TestkitList> snapshot) {
                                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                          case ConnectionState.none:
                                            return Text('none');
                                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                            return Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator());
                                          case ConnectionState.active:
                                            return Text('');
                                          case ConnectionState.done:
                                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                              return Text(
                                                'error',
                                                //  '${snapshot.error}',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.red),
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              return DropdownButtonFormField<
                                                  String>(
                                                hint:
                                                    Text("Select Testkit Name"),
                                                value: _selectedTestkit,
                                                onChanged: (newValue) async {
                                                  _selectedTestkit = newValue;
                                                  _selectedTestType =
                                                      await getTestType();
                                                  setState(() {});
                                                  print(
                                                      "the below line is printed in dropdownfield");
                                                  print(_selectedTestType);
                                                },
                                                validator: (value) => value ==
                                                        null
                                                    ? 'Please select the Testkit'
                                                    : null,
                                                items: (snapshot.data.data)
                                                    .map((item) =>
                                                        DropdownMenuItem<
                                                            String>(
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            item.attributes.name
                                                                        .length >
                                                                    30
                                                                ? item
                                                                    .attributes
                                                                    .name
                                                                    .substring(
                                                                        0, 30)
                                                                : item
                                                                    .attributes
                                                                    .name,
                                                          ),
                                                          value: item.id,
                                                        ))
                                                    .toList(),
                                              );
                                            }
                                        }
                                      }),
                                )),
                              ),
```

Now plugin example for autocompleteFormField is like below:

```
SimpleAutocompleteFormField<Person>(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Person', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                suggestionsHeight: 80.0,
                itemBuilder: (context, person) => Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                    Text(person!.name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Text(person.address)
                  ]),
                ),
                onSearch: (search) async => people
                    .where((person) =>
                        person.name.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()) ||
                        person.address.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList(),
                itemFromString: (string) {
                  final matches = people.where((person) => person.name.toLowerCase() == string.toLowerCase());
                  return matches.isEmpty ? null : matches.first;
                },
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectedPerson = value),
                onSaved: (value) => setState(() => selectedPerson = value),
                validator: (person) => person == null ? 'Invalid person.' : null,
              )
```

somehow I am not able to make it pickup and work as whether I am using classname `TestkitList' or` snapshot.data.data' replacing the `person` which is in my case is a future.

Comment: Are you happy with using external package? `flutter-typeahead` is a good package for auto complete. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

Answer (score 0):

You could flutter-typeahead package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead/install

```
TypeAheadField(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
    autofocus: true,
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder()
    )
  ),
  suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
    return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
      title: Text(suggestion['name']),
      subtitle: Text('\$${suggestion['price']}'),
    );
  },
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ProductPage(product: suggestion)
    ));
  },
)
```